# How to pass selected id in url through AngularJS routing and get data in console.log?

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

Im Passing Selected Car Id in Url and trying to get data in console.log don't know where i'm missing may be i'm confused checking too much solution in stackoverflow - here is my code :

//Controller.js

```
     $scope.chooseACar = function(selectCarId)
            { 
               $scope.selectCarId = $stateParams.selectCarId;
                console.log($scope.selectCarId);
            }
```

//App.js

```
    .state('main.step3', 
    {
        url: '/step2/:selectCarId',
        templateUrl: 'pages/step3.html'
    });
```

//services.js

```
get: function(selectCarId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < carListData.length; i++) {
      if (carListData[i].id === parseInt(selectCarId)) {
        console.log(carListData[i]);
        return carListData[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

// HTML Code

```
<a type="submit" href="#/main/step2/{{selectCarList.id}}" class="button button-yellow button-full submitBtn" style="color:#000; display:block">CHOOSE A CAR</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App.js (if you are getting ID in url no need to modify.)

```
.state('main.step2', {
    name: 'slectcarID'
    url: '/step2/:selectCarId',
    templateUrl: 'pages/step3.html'
});
```

and to get the data in controller use $stateParams

```
console.log($stateParams.selectCarId);
```

or

```
$scope.selectCarId = $stateParams.selectCarId;
console.log($scope.selectCarId);
```

Try either only ng-click or ui-sref

Comment: Getting Undefined Value!!

Comment: Is the ID getting appended in URL ?

Comment: Hey try removing ng-href="#/main/step2/{{selectCarList.id}}" in your HTML. and check if selectCar value is getting pased in chooseAcar function.

Comment: I removed ng-href. Now button is not working !! its not getting clicked

Comment: Are you sure you want it <a> tag ? Please change a to div tag or just remove ng-click from the html  and try

Comment: I did some changes in code now im getting id in url but not able to get data in console.log.

Comment: In angularjs You have to use stateparams to access the id appended in url
$stateParams.(id name)

Comment: i have updated same thing in above code. and Now im getting Id appended in url but the problem is i'm not getting data form that id.

Comment: Like the other answer, I actually work with ui-sref, but I think it should work with your code too just with ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ui-sref** instead of href

#### HTML

```
<a type="submit" ui-sref="main.step3({carId : selectCarList.id})"
   class="button button-yellow button-full submitBtn" 
   style="color:#000; display:block">CHOOSE A CAR
</a>
```

#### App.js

```
.state('main.step3', 
{
    url: '/step2/:selectCarId',
    templateUrl: 'pages/step3.html',
    controller: `Your Controller Name`,
    params: { carId: null, }
});
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.chooseACar = function(){ 
                                  $scope.selectCarId = $stateParams.carId;
                                  console.log($scope.selectCarId);
                              }
```

Comment: Do i need to define controller again. i mean i already define main controller and I don't want to define it again.

Comment: No need, in your controller it self.

Comment: so you define controller here do i put my controller name .state('main.step3', 
{
    url: '/step2/:selectCarId',
    templateUrl: 'pages/step3.html',
    controller: ctrl,
    params: { carId: null, }
});

Comment: in app.js along with url,templateUrl include controller and params

Comment: here controller means, the name of the controller from which view is rendering

Comment: Error: Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: Param values not valid for state 'main.step3')